# 'ERROR not implemented' with Angular4 web worker

Tags: angular, web-worker

I used the steps described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40814324/angular-2-web-worker-ui-not-running/40820019#40820019) to convert my Angular4 app to a web worker. When I run the app, I see the following error:

[image]

The change I have from my existing Angular4 app and the new one is the support of the web worker.

The error does not give any clue of what component or code is causing this. Is there a tracing that I can add to somewhere to find what is causing this error?

**---- UPDATE 6/28 -----**

The error is generated from the following code

`WorkerDomAdapter.prototype.getCookie = function (name) { throw 'not implemented'; };` in **platform-webworker.umd.js**

The `getCookie` call is made by **http.umd.js**.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution to this problem is to create a custom `XSRFStrategy` so the Angular `http` module uses the custom rather than the default one.

```
import { HttpModule, XSRFStrategy, Request } from '@angular/http';

...

class CustomXSRFStrategy extends XSRFStrategy
{
    public configureRequest(req: Request) { /* */ }
}

...

 providers: [{ provide: XSRFStrategy, useValue: new CustomXSRFStrategy() }]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't access cookies with a web-worker, as well as `localStorage` or `sessionStorage` aren't accessible.

A similar topic with some more information can be found here: [Accessing localStorage from a webWorker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6179159/accessing-localstorage-from-a-webworker)